# S3 Bucket Encryption Policy - Put a new file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see the below S3 bucket policy in the bucket that I am trying to put a file -

```
{
            "Sid": "EncryptedPutObject",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "AES256",
                        "aws:kms"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I am seeing "access denied" error when I try to copy a test file. Using the same profile , I am able to list the contents of the bucket. Should I add any parameters to encrypt and send the file over to S3?

```
aws s3 cp test.csv s3://<bucketname> --profile <profilename>
```

Comment: The policy requires you to request server side encryption using AES256 or KMS so you need to supply SSE parameters (--sse-c-* or --sse-kms-*) when using aws s3 cp.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. How can I get that I need to key that I can pass in as part of the command?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with creating and using encryption keys then I would recommend talking to the owner of this S3 bucket who can presumably advise you, given that they have implemented this policy.

Comment: I ran this command and it seemed to work. Is -c or -kms not required? - aws s3 cp test.csv <Bucket Name> --sse AES256.  If you could help post an answer , I will accept. Thanks for your help.